# Can't access account viewer

Tags: accounts, ledger

I get this error message when trying to use Account Viewer:

> This security key doesn't look familiar.
> Please try a different one.

[image: Screenshot of error message]

I'm using the same ledger I've always used - anybody have an idea of how to resolve this?